# Is there a way to view another user in Mac OS Yosemite, like screensharing your own computer?

Tags: macos, networking, mac, screen-sharing

Is there a way to view two users on the same computer at the same time on Mac OS?

I've noticed when logging on over the network using Mac OS screen sharing to a computer that has more than one user, I can pick the user I log on as.

Now, if I am actually on a computer with more than one user, is there an equivalent where I can log on as the second user without logging out as the first one?

At the moment on computer A I use Screen Sharing log onto computer B, where I fire up Screen Sharing and log on back to computer A as a different user. It works, but network lag is an annoyance.

Can I do this without going through this rigamarole?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

- Go to System Preferences -> Users & Groups
- Click on Login **Options**
- Unlock / Authenticate
- Turn on Show Fast User Switching Menu as

  - I normally recommend Account name
- Close System Preferences

This will enable Fast User Switching.  The current user is still logged in, so you have both users logged in at the same time.  If you are done, please remember to **log out of the user** instead of Fast User Switching back.

If you fast user switch back to the original user, you haven't logged the other user out, so you are consuming more RAM, and resources than you need to.

Comment: Thanks, Ben, but that's not quite what I'm looking for. I have a program running under the second user that I want to be able to control without logging out of being the first user. Let's say I'm running a really long After Effects action as user 2 then switch back to being user 1 (as per your suggestion) - the After Effects action continues under user 2 even though I'm no longer "there." I want to be able to look in on how the action is doing without having to log out of being user 1. Right now I use the technique detailed above which requires two computers and two Screen Shares. Non-optimal.